# How to view the logs in the Run button in android studio?

Tags: android, android-studio, android-studio-flamingo

I[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TDsUd.png) want to view the logs in the part of the Run button, I do see the logs in the Logcat window, but I update my android and now I cannot view the Logs in the Run window

I don't have any observations, I've searched for some configuration but I can't find where it is

Answer (score 0):

your target tab - Logcat - 2 times righter Run

Answer (score 0):

[image]

Unfortunately you can't view the logs in the run tab, but if you go to the settings you will be able to make it automatically open logcat after running so I hope that helps